# Once msg box is clicked then it should direct me to Input box

Tags: vba, excel

This is my `Inputbox` code:

```
Private Sub Q1No_Click()
    Dim myResponse As String
    myResponse = InputBox("Reason for not atten Morning MOM", "Mention Reason", 0, 0)
    Range("G4") = myResponse
End Sub
```

This my `Msgbox` code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("C22")
    If Application.Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "You must select the answer from the list" 
    End If
```

How do I link these two?

Comment: I think you might have provided the wrong / incomplete code for the `Msgbox`? Can you please clarify?

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("C22")
    If Application.Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "You must select the answer from the list"
    End If

Comment: Next time, please update the question instead of adding it as comment. I did this one for you for now. Anyways, what do you mean by linking, please clarify that as well. I understand you want to incorporate the 1st code to the 2nd but how do you want it done?

Comment: input box should not empty, if empty msg box should display"mention the reason", once i clicked ok, then it again redirect me to input box to enter the reason......

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like:

```
Private Sub Q1No_Click()
    Dim myResponse As String
    Do
        myResponse = InputBox("Reason for not atten Morning MOM", "Mention Reason", 0, 0)
        If myResponse = "" Then MsgBox "mention the reason"
    Loop While myResponse = ""
    Range("G4") = myResponse
End Sub
```

Comment: @PraveenTyson, did you try this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, have a go at this:

```
Sub marine()
    Dim myprompt As String, myresponse As String

    myprompt = "Reason for not attending morning MOM:"
    With Sheet1 '/* this is your sheet */
        Do
            myresponse = InputBox(myprompt, "Mention Reason")
            myprompt = "No reason provided." & vbNewLine & _
                       "Please provide a reason and try again."
        Loop Until Len(myresponse) > 0
        .Range("G4").Value2 = myresponse
    End With
End Sub
```

This will enforce putting something on the `Inputbox`.
I abandoned the use of `Msgbox` and revised the prompt of the `Inputbox` instead if the user didn't put anything on it.

Comment: There is no escape out of this. Could be a welcome addition :). Also I would go with Sheets(1)...nice solution though!

Comment: thanks bro...its working.....but their is small issue...but i solve it.....

Comment: .Range("G4").Value2 = myresponse   Because of this  dot before range...the data i enter in inputbox was not showing.....anyway thanks dude....

Comment: hi bro...in single sheet i have multi radio button......if i click first row radio button last row was uncheked...what to do

Comment: @PraveenTyson That is the expected response of a radio button. For further assistance, please post another question :)